# Alternative solution for activiti engines

Tags: reporting, workflow

I wanted to perform a batch of http requests in java spring boot application and I need a mechanism to show the current status of this batch activity.

We can group this http calls into certain stages/categories and we want to show the status of each stage to the user.

We use activity engines in our application and I want to know whether there is any other software or library which is best suitable for this requirement.

We basically want to generate a report which shows the status of each stage similar to Jenkins blue ocean report.

Please share your suggestions about the library or any other alternative solution in Java/Spring to implement this requirement.